# How to remove Outliers in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to remove outliers from my dataset "train" for which purpose I've decided to use z-score or IQR.

I'm running Jupyter notebook on Microsoft Python Client for SQL Server.

I've tried for z-score:

```
from scipy import stats
train[(np.abs(stats.zscore(train)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

for IQR:

```
Q1 = train.quantile(0.02)
Q3 = train.quantile(0.98)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
train = train[~((train < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(train > (Q3 + 1.5 * 
IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

...which returns...

for z-score:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

for IQR:

> TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()

My train dataset looks like:

```
# Number of each type of column
print('Training data shape: ', train.shape)
train.dtypes.value_counts()
```

> Training data shape:  (300000, 111) int32      66 float64    30 object     15 dtype: int64

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably missing a few casts. But you would need to show more about your data sets in order to know

Comment: What does your train data look like? Does it contain any categorical features?

Comment: I've just edited the Q for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having trouble with your code because you're trying to calculate `zscore` on categorical columns.

To avoid this, you should first separate your train into parts with numerical and categorical features:

```
num_train = train.select_dtypes(include=["number"])
cat_train = train.select_dtypes(exclude=["number"])
```

and only after that calculate index of rows to keep:

```
idx = np.all(stats.zscore(num_train) < 3, axis=1)
```

and finally add the two pieces together:

```
train_cleaned = pd.concat([num_train.loc[idx], cat_train.loc[idx]], axis=1)
```

For IQR part:

```
Q1 = num_train.quantile(0.02)
Q3 = num_train.quantile(0.98)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
idx = ~((num_train < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (num_train > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)
train_cleaned = pd.concat([num_train.loc[idx], cat_train.loc[idx]], axis=1)
```

Please let us know if you have any further questions.

PS

As well, you might consider one more approach for dealing with outliers with [pandas.DataFrame.clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html), which will clip outliers on a case-by-case basis instead of dropping a row altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to use z-score and got an error: TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences.

Comment: This worked for me: num_train = train.select_dtypes(include=['number'])
cat_train = train.select_dtypes(exclude=['number'])

Comment: Have you gotten `idx` filled with booleans `True` and `False`? If so, use it to index `num_train` and `cat_train`. It worked on my laptop perfectly.

Comment: I did not. However, the IQR way seems to work fine and is more sutaible for my purpose otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **autooptimizer** module.

pip install autooptimizer

from autooptimizer.process import outlier_removal